# Omni Channel:Can we route a case to all members of a queue

Tags: visualforce, community, salesforce1-app, omnichannel

I am facing some difficulty to understand Omnichannel, In omnichannel can we route the case notification (work item) to all members of a queue at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a Case Assignment Rule and route the Case to a queue, see https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=creating_assignment_rules.htm&type=5. Here is described how Omni-Channel Routing works: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=omnichannel_routing.htm&type=5